# Programmatically getting the stream name

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

System Information

Spring Cloud Data Flow Cloud Foundry: v1.1.0.RELEASE
Pivotal Cloud Foundry: v1.7.12
CF Client (Windows): cf.exe version 6.23.1+a70deb3.2017-01-13
cf-v3-plugin: 0.6.7

I would like to inject the stream name into a bean defined in my custom source module. From reviewing the `/env` end-point of a deployed stream I found the `SPRING_CLOUD_APPLICATION_GROUP` system property so I've injected this into my bean like so.

```
/**
 * application name
 */
@Value("#{ systemProperties['SPRING_CLOUD_APPLICATION_GROUP'] }")
private String applicationName;
```

The issue here is that this appears to be tied to the Cloud Foundry deployer, which from my perspective is not good for portability.

In Spring XD the `xd.stream.name` placeholder existed for this purpose.

Is there any way to do this in a way that is portable.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

All deployer implementations should honor this variable name, so you should be good to go.

There is no *strong* requirement that this is passed as an environment variable though (your code assumes *system property*, not even sure it works, does it?). Using the Spring `Environment` abstraction is the best way to stay portable here.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. The system property is working as part of a integration test, but obviously I was controlling how the property was being injected. I never got to deploying it to PCF.

The `Environment` approach did work though. Thanks.